# AWS Cognito delete-custom-attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

There is add-custom-attributes command in cognito-idp but no delete-custom-attributes?

How do I delete them?

Answer (score 51):

Never mind.

This is not doable at the moment.
Under the [Custom Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes) it has mentioned that:

> Cannot be removed or changed once added to the user pool.

Comment: I wonder why the custom attributes are  non deletable, that does not make sense to me! :/

Comment: This seems like a strange decision, assuming there are no users in the pool with this attribute set. I now have an attribute in the pool which will never be used because I created it as a number when the AWS SDK expects everything as a string. `class com.amazon.coral.value.json.numbers.TruncatingBigNumber can not be converted to an String`

Comment: Given that we have a limit of 50 custom attributes per user pool, we should be able to delete, custom attributes which are no longer required.

Answer (score -3):

I know this question is over 4 years old. But for me it appears at the top in a Google search. As far as I know there is currently no option in the Cognito UI to delete attributes. But you can use the AWS-CLI to delete the attributes. Here is the official description:

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-delete-user-attributes.html?highlight=admin%20delete%20user%20attributes

I know that this only works for specific users, but one could easy write a batch for this. Don't take me wrong ... it should be a feature of the CLI or the UI, but a batch is at least a workaround.

Comment: hmmm not right... the link you have put is to remove the attributes from the particular User not Attribute itself.

Comment: As the previous commenter points out, this is a misleading solution. The API call just allows the admin to delete an attribute on a specific user, not remove its definition from the userpool.